How to fetch an api from backend with Axios Error
I am trying to fetch data from springboot backend with axios in vite+react frontend but it results in error only while fetching data id wise but the url is working properly in localhost with id.
The url is:-
http://localhost:8080/api/products/1
But through frontend the error shows:-
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
Error fetching product: AxiosError
And in Backend the error shows:-
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; For input string: "NaN"
Frontend:- Product.jsx
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {  useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "../axios";

const Product = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
        const productId = parseInt(id, 10);
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/products/${productId}`);
        setProduct(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching product:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchProduct();
  }, [id]);





  if (!product) {
    return (
      <h2 className="text-center" style={{ padding: "10rem" }}>
        Loading...
      </h2>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="containers">
        <div className="right-column">
          <div className="product-description">
            <span>{product.category}</span>
            <h1>{product.name}</h1>
            <h5>{product.brand}</h5>
            <p>{product.description}</p>
          </div>

          <div className="product-price">
            <span>{"$" + product.price}</span>
            <button
              className={`cart-btn ${!product.productAvailable ? "disabled-btn" : ""}`}
              disabled={!product.productAvailable}
            >
              {product.productAvailable ? "Add to cart" : "Out of Stock"}
            </button>
            <h6>
              Stock Available :{" "}
              <i style={{ color: "green", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                {product.stockQuantity}
              </i>
            </h6>
            <p className="release-date">
              <h6>Product listed on:</h6>
              <i>{product.releaseDate}</i>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="update-button ">
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              type="button"
          
            >
              Update
            </button>
        
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              type="button"
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Product;


In Backend id is initialized as :- private int productID;
Router and route declaration:-
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Cart from "./components/Cart.jsx";
import AddProduct from "./components/AddProduct";
import Product from "./components/Product";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { AppProvider } from "./Context/context";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


function App() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("");

  const handleCategorySelect = (category) => {
    setSelectedCategory(category);
    console.log("Selected category:", category);
  };
  const addToCart = (product) => {
    const existingProduct = cart.find((item) => item.id === product.id);
    if (existingProduct) {
      setCart(
        cart.map((item) =>
          item.id === product.id
            ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 }
            : item
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCart([...cart, { ...product, quantity: 1 }]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar onSelectCategory={handleCategorySelect}
         />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <Home addToCart={addToCart} selectedCategory={selectedCategory}
              />
            }
          />
          <Route path="/add_product" element={<AddProduct />} />
          <Route path="/products" element={<Product  />} />
          <Route path="products/:id" element={<Product  />} />
          <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AppProvider>
  );
}

export default App;


Backend:-
ProductController.java
package com.shristi.ecom_proj.controller;

import com.shristi.ecom_proj.Model.Product;
import com.shristi.ecom_proj.service.productService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ProductController {


    @Autowired
    private productService service;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String greet(){
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> getAllProducts(){
        return service.getAllProducts();
    }


    @GetMapping("/products/{id}")
    public Product getProduct(@PathVariable int id){
        return service.getProductById(id);
    }
}


ProductService.java
@Autowired
    private productRepo repo;

public Product getProductById(int id) {
        return repo.findById(id).get();

Product.java
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int productID;
    private String Name;}


You never added the additional debugging details requested in SG: between navigating the frontend to "/products/someIdValue" and the backend throwing the error: (1) what is the value of id from const { id } = useParams(), (2) the value of productId used in the fetch call, (3) the request URL, and (4) the value of id at public Product getProduct(@PathVariable int id){

From the log output I would assume that the actual API call looks like this http://localhost:8080/api/products/NaN. NaN is returned by parseInt(), if the inpu is not a valid number. So I would start by debugging there. Is the id in the effect properly initialized?
